# Read value one by one by using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, properties

I have a properties file as below:

```
FileToRead=project.xml,CheckFile.ini
RunTimeFile=MyRuntime.xml
```

I want to read the comma separated value of parameter `FileToRead` one by one by using `For` loop of VBScript.

The script I have tried some sample like this for testing:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

listFile = fso.OpenTextFile("MyFile.properties").ReadLine
listcheck = Split(listFile, vbCrLf)

For Each MyValue In listcheck
    segments = Split(line, ",")
    WScript.Echo "SimpleCheck" 
Next
```

And is there any possibility to use `Or` condition inside `If` block in VBS?

Comment: Your script only reads the first line if the file, is that intentional?

Comment: I want to read both the parameters from the property file, not only the first line. It could be fine if we specify the Key and read the Value.

Comment: You need to do a lot more than your code is doing right now. For one thing you should use `ReadAll` instead of `ReadLine` if you're going to split the content of the file at newlines afterwards. Then you need to split each line at `=` so you can separate values from keys. Then split the values at `,` and process them with a second `For Each` loop.

Comment: Please read up on [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/czxefwt8%28v%3dvs.84%29) [Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/ebkhfaaz%28v%3dvs.84%29).

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the value of the property "FileToRead" using the property name "FileToRead" ? (Like we do ${FileToRead} in ANT) Using Split, I am able to separate the property name and value, but it would be great if able to fetch the value using the property name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Dictionary to store all the lines in form of key value pair
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("<InputFilePath>", 1)

'Reading the file and storing properties in the dictionary
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  line = file.Readline
  splittedLine = Split(line,"=")
  if UBound(splittedLine)=1 then
    dict.Add splittedLine(0),splittedLine(1)
  end if
Loop
file.Close

'Now get the value from dictionary using key name FileToRead
valFileToRead = dict.item("FileToRead")
arrFiles=Split(valFileToRead,",")
for i=0 to UBound(arrFiles)
  'Do anything with the values
  msgBox(arrFiles(i))
next
```

Yes you can use `OR` keyword inside if

```
if Condition1 OR Condition 2 then
   'Code
end if
```